# How to convert a php variable into a string(From <form:input>), to send lat, and long?

Tags: php, forms, latitude-longitude, string-conversion

I have this code below. The $address variable must get a string, in order to convert, and send it to a database. I have a form with inputs, which I store in further variables. How should i convert the values to get lat and long?

```
         $address = "Rákoscsaba, Nagyréde utca 8. 1172"; // Google HQ
         $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
         $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
         $output= json_decode($geocode);
         $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
         $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

It s working... the 3 variables I want to use: $user_telepules, $user_utca', $user_irsz

I've already tried these ways:

```
         $address =['user_telepules'].','.['user_utca'].['user_irsz']; 
         $address =(string)$user_telepules.','.(string)$user_utca.(string)$user_irsz;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I get it. Show us few data samples from this three variables. Maybe there is problem with something else, not string format.

How are you passing variables from input? Have you checked, if they actually exist and pass inputs from form?

Comment: Yes, they are woking fine Every other variable loads up fine into the database except this one.  
                        <td width = "100"><font size="5">Település:</font></td>
                        <td><input name = "user_telepules" type = "text" 
                           id = "user_telepules"></td>

Comment: I have tried your script and it`s working fine.
This is how I build address: $address = $_POST['user_telepules'].','.$_POST['user_utca'].' '.$_POST['user_irsz'];

Comment: Thx, you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

It should be already a string, form inputs always passes strings to php interpreter.

```
$address = $user_telepules.",".$user_utca." ".$user_irsz;
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working :S